# ¿Como puedo llamar a diferentes páginas segun el tipo de usuario despues de iniciar sesión?

Tags: php

Buen día amigos de esta comunidad de programadores, en esta ocasión vengo con un detalle, tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión donde accedo sin problemas como tipo de usuario cliente y me muestra la página o panel del cliente hasta ahí todo bien,tengo otro archivo llamado administrador, pero quiero iniciar sesión como tipo usuario administrador y que me muestre su página o panel correspondiente he intentado hacer un condicional desde el login.php pero no he obtenido el resultado que quiero, es ahí donde no he logrado hacer esa funcionalidad.

**Login.php**

```
<?php

  session_start();

  include("conexion.php");

  if (isset($_SESSION['ID_usuario'])) {
    header('location: cliente.php');
  } 

  $errores ='';

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $idusuario = filter_var (strtolower ($_POST['ID_usuario']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $pass = $_POST['Pass'];

    if (empty($idusuario) or empty($pass) ) {
    $errores .='<li>¡ Favor de llenar los campos !</li>';
   } else {
    $statement = $conexion->prepare('SELECT * FROM  usuarios  WHERE ID_usuario =:Idusuario  AND  Pass =:pass ');
    $statement->execute(array(':Idusuario' => $idusuario , ':pass' => $pass));
   
    $resultado = $statement ->fetch();
    
    if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $idusuario;  
   if ($_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] == "C") {
           header('location: cliente.php');            
 } elseif ($_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] == "A") 
  header('location: administrador.php');
   }else {
       $errores .='<li>¡ Datos incorrectos verifique el usuario o contraseña !</li>';
    }  
   } 
  }

  require 'views/login.view.php';

?>
```

**cliente.php**

```
<?php

 include("conexion.php");

 if (isset($_SESSION['ID_usuario'])) {

 $ideuser = $_SESSION['ID_usuario'];

 $query_sesion = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID_usuario = '$ideuser' AND  Iduser >='1'");
$query_sesion->execute();

$sesion_usuarios = $query_sesion->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($sesion_usuarios as $sesion_usuario) {
$NombreUser = $sesion_usuario['Nombre_usuario'];
$TipoUser = $sesion_usuario['Tipo_usuario'];
  }
 }
 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="es">

 <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,  minimum-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Tech center</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/cliente.css" />
  </head>

 <body>
   <header class="encabezado">
      <div class="contenedor">
         <input type="checkbox" id="btnmenu" />
         <label for="btnmenu"><img src="image/menu.png" alt="" /></label>
         <div class="logo">
            <h1>Tech Center</h1>
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Ver catálago</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Usuario:
                        <?php echo '<span style= "color: #82D8F0">'.$sesion_usuario['Nombre_usuario'].'</span>';?></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Tipo de usuario:
                        <?php echo '<span style= "color: #82D8F0">'.$sesion_usuario['Tipo_usuario'].'</span>';?></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="contenido">
        <h2>Tech Center</h2>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <section id="footer">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="colum1">
                <p>
                    Copyright ©2021 Tech Center Soporte│Calle Alameda Col.
                    Guerrero, Reynosa,Tamps.Todos los derechos reservados
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="colum2">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/logotipo-circular-de-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/whatsapp.png" alt="whatsapp" /></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/youtube.png" alt="youtube" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

**administrador.php**

```
<?php

  include("conexion.php");

  if (isset($_SESSION['ID_usuario'])) {

  $ideuser = $_SESSION['ID_usuario'];

  $query_sesion = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE ID_usuario = '$ideuser' AND Iduser >='1'");
 $query_sesion->execute();

 $sesion_usuarios = $query_sesion->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 foreach ($sesion_usuarios as $sesion_usuario) {
 $NombreUser = $sesion_usuario['Nombre_usuario'];
 $TipoUser = $sesion_usuario['Tipo_usuario'];
   }
  }
 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">

 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8" />
 <meta name="viewport"
    content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
      <title>Tech center</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css" />
      </head>

  <body>
      <header class="encabezado">
        <div class="contenedor">
        <input type="checkbox" id="btnmenu" />
        <label for="btnmenu"><img src="image/menu.png" alt="" /></label>
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Tech Center</h1>
        </div>

        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Registrar producto</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Ver inventario</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Usuario:
                        <?php echo '<span style= "color: #82D8F0">'.$sesion_usuario['Nombre_usuario'].'</span>';?></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">Tipo de usuario:
                        <?php echo '<span style= "color: #82D8F0">'.$sesion_usuario['Tipo_usuario'].'</span>';?></a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="cerrar_sesion.php">Cerrar sesión</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

<main>
    <div class="contenido">
        <h2>Tech Center</h2>
    </div>
</main>

<footer>
    <section id="footer">
        <div class="contenedor">
            <div class="colum1">
                <p>
                    Copyright ©2021 Tech Center Soporte│Calle Alameda Col.
                    Guerrero, Reynosa,Tamps.Todos los derechos reservados
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="colum2">
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/logotipo-circular-de-facebook.png" alt="Facebook" /></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/whatsapp.png" alt="whatsapp" /></a>
                <a href="#" target="_blank">
                    <img src="image/youtube.png" alt="youtube" /></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta. En  `login.php` no hay nada relativo a lo que nos dices en la pregunta sobre el usuario administrador.

Comment: En `login.php` tú estás haciendo esta comparación: `if ($_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] == "C") {`  pero resulta que **en ningún momento estás guardando el tipo de usuario en la variable de sesión**. Si quieres comparar en base a eso, debes primero guardar el tipo de usuario haciendo esto: `if ($resultado !== false) {
        $_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $idusuario; $_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] = $resultado['Tipo_usuario'];` En esta línea: `$_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] = $resultado['Tipo_usuario']` estarías agregando el dato a la variable de sesión.

Comment: O, puedes prescindir de la variable de sesión y comparar en base a los datos obtenidos desde la consulta SQL, como sugiere acertadamente @Excorpion en su respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dices que has intentado hacer algo en el login.php, pero eso no se vee acá.

Aunque es correcto, luego de iniciar sesión, debes buscar el tipo de usuario, y según el tipo de usuario, es donde debes hacer el header siguiente.

```
//login.php
if ($resultado !== false) { //Si el resultado no es false
  $_SESSION['ID_usuario'] = $idusuario;//cargamos el ID a session
  $_SESSION['Tipo_Usuario'] = $tipo;//cargamos el tipoUsuario a session, **debes obtenerlo primero**.
  $tipoUsuario = $resultado["Tipo_usuario"];
  if($tipoUsuario === "C"){ //analizamos el tipo de usuario
    header('location: cliente.php');
    exit;
  }
  if($tipoUsuario === "A"){ //analizamos el tipo de usuario
    header('location: administrador.php');
    exit;
  }else{
    echo "Ha habido un problema con el tipoUsuario, por favo contactar al administrador";
  }
} else {
  $errores .='<li>¡ Datos incorrectos verifique el usuario o contraseña !</li>';
}
```

Luego, en las páginas correspondientes, lo que debes verificar es que el tipo corresponda a la página en cuestión.
El cliente debe venir con su tipo correspondiente y mismo caso con el administrador, sino serán redireccionados a otro lado, o les cerramos la sesión.

Comment: Buen día amigo, lo tenia de esta forma en el login.php  `f ($_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] == "C") {
           header('location: cliente.php');
           } elseif ($_SESSION['ID_usuario'] ['Tipo_usuario'] == "A") {
        header('location: administrador.php');
          }`  pero lo borre, pero ya casi lo estaba logrando, tu respuesta me ha sido de gran utilidad.

Comment: Tienes que agregar eso en la publicación, por que si dices que has intentado algo y no se vee, no sabemos que has hecho. Y taampoco COMO lo has hecho. Ahora mismo veo que estás analizando el session de una forma muy extraña, no es el session el que debes analizar.